# Do the facebook API terms allow to import facebook events, videos and photos into my community site?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm planning a community site for dancing. It will allow to organise dance events and also add videos, photos to dance events. To offer a nice user experience, I would like users to be able to add events by scanning their wall (and their friends) to add photos, videos or events to the site. Of course this will only happen with the users permission and on his request.

The use cases include

- add a facebook event by searching or entering the facebook event url to my application, where it can be organised further (tagged for example) and associated with videos and pictures from other sources than facebook
- add a video that a user or his friends posted before, where it also can be associated with other data (songs, locations...). This is normally a youtube video.
- add a photo from his own album to my site, where again the pictures can be associated with events. It would also be great if other users were allowed to add a public album from a friend or other user to the site.

Is this allowed by the facebook platform terms of use?

Greetings,

Nils

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is allowed. You can cache the data of the current logged user, asking him permission to access *events, albums*, and more.

If you need to access data whenever the user is offline, you must require the **access_offline** permission, wich gives you an unexpirable accesss token (in my experience, the token eventually expires one time a month or so, i don't understand why). With that token you can fetch all the data from that user profile.

I believe the best practice for your project would be to fetch the data, cache it into a mysql database, and connect all the elements you want from outside facebook. I did something like that in a site, I use the administrator's facebook account as my backoffice.

One thing about images: just save the link path and they are always available, no need of token or anything else. Facebook never deletes them. Never, even when the user removes them from his albums or when the user is banned.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Cant post a coment to your answer maxijib :-( so i will post as an answer. Nevertheless offline_access is deprecated you can read about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) facebook is giving you 60 day access token instead which can be obtained when the user logs in to your app. Directly by the [server side login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/#step1) or [exchanging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) the short live token for long-live token.

For the other func. you can use [Graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) or [FQL Query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)(not sure).

I think you can do almost anything with the api, if the user approves it and it is not a spam ;)